# AS3 3D character customization?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d

Is it possible to make 3D character customization for game in flash? Any ideas, tips about that?. In 2D it's very simple but i don't know where i should begin in 3D. First of all - how character customization works in rpg games? Is character body and all cusomizable parts like hair face, solid model? Or it's just different objects in one container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are currently many engines in Flash which support 3D; you might find that one of them has examples of what you want.
From my experience it's what the previous guy said, plus that you can actually rig clothing along with the body. Parts like hats/helms, swords, shields, etc. are attached to their suitable nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way is swapping base meshes and textures, and in some cases the engines also support morph shapes, which is basically vertex deformation relative to the base mesh.

Other parts such as hair, weapons etc are just attached to the main rig's attachment points.